# How do I store additional information in each event and load it from a MySQL database?

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm creating a timekeeping application that uses fullcalendar. Essentially I want to be able to store the following information into an event: Date, start time(when you started working), end time(when you stopped working), location, and comments. These events will essentially be all day, because there will never be a time that extends beyond one day, and I only care about the time stamps so I can determine the total amount of hours worked.

On a previous version of FullcalendarV2, I would just store the information into the events directly as fields. I.e event.starttime = "07:00:00", event.endtime = "09:00:00", and event.location = "meeting", etc... But in Version 4 I don't seem to have the ability to do that anymore. When I try to load in these additional parameters into my events, and I call event.location or event.comments it just returns NULL/undefined now.

Heres the code that loads the information from the sql database

```
<?php

    //load.php

    $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=chronos_test', 'root', '');

    $data = array();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM timesheets ORDER BY id";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
    $startArr = explode(":", $row['start_time']);
    $startT = ($startArr[0] * 60) + $startArr[1];
    $endArr = explode(":", $row['end_time']);
    $endT = ($endArr[0] * 60) + $endArr[1];
    $hoursWorked = ($endT - $startT) / 60;
     $data[] = array(
       'id' => $row['id'],
       'title' => "Hours Worked - ".$hoursWorked." hrs",
       'date'  => $row['date'],
       'starttime' => $row['start_time'],
       'endtime' => $row['end_time'],
       'location' => $row['location'],
       'comments' => $row['comments']
     );
    }

    echo json_encode($data);

    ?>


Here's the code that I use to get the events for my calendar(This is in a   separate calendar file)


            events: 
            {
                id: '1',
                url: './php/load.php',
                method: 'POST',
            }
```

Comment: Have you got a specific problem you'd like help with? You've sort of told us what you're trying to do, but not what's going wrong. It's unclear what the issue is

Comment: I'm trying to get the events to store the information, but in this new version of Full calendar it doesn't let me store other parameters other than the ones they have set like "start, end, id"

So location and comments aren't being saved into these events as parameters that I can send and receive from my SQL DB

Comment: Yes it does, it just changes where it puts them in the finished events. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing where it talks about the `extendedProps` object. That's where all custom fields get placed. So `event.extendedProps.location` should work, for example. (If you're migrating from an old version of fullCalendar this change is also mentioned in the [upgrade guide](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3#event-source))